# Magento 2: Set custom class on modal background

Tags: magento2, css, uicomponent, modal

How do I add a custom class to the background of a modal widget in Magento 2?

I'm able to change the class for the main modal `<aside>` with the `modalClass` config property but want to change the class on the background div behind the modal, which isn't a child of the `<aside>`.

This is how I set the `modalClass` currently:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"My_Module/js/my-modal":{"modalClass":"foo"}}'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source code for modals in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/modal.js`, I found the option: `overlayClass` which I could use in my initialisation object to set my own custom class:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"My_Module/js/my-modal":{"modalClass":"foo","overlayClass":"bar"}}'></div>
```